# build native openCV sources with Android Studio and NDK

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to include some native cpp sources in my android app. I'm using Android Studio 1.0 with the gradle build system. I have three modules: my android app, the android opencv libs, the cpp sources (in the jni folder)

The build process gives me the following error:

```
    D:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r10c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\include\bits\stl_pair.h
    Error:(96, 12) error: redefinition of 'struct std::pair<_T1, _T2>'
    Error:(214, 5) error: redefinition of 'template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)'
    ... and some other redefinitions with some other errors in other files.
```

It seems that the include paths are partially wrong or that there are duplicated headers (stl_pair.h) in the NDK This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    ndk{
        moduleName "Native"
        cFlags  "-I'D:\\OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\\sdk\\native\\jni\\include' " +
                "-I'D:\\NVPACK\\android-ndk-r10c\\sources\\cxx-stl\\gnu-libstdc++\\4.9\\include' " +
                "-I'D:\\NVPACK\\android-ndk-r10c\\sources\\cxx-stl\\gnu-libstdc++\\4.9\\libs\\armeabi-v7a\\include'"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

In cFlags I point to the openCV sources and to the c++ standard sources as described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html). This works all fine until the above error.

I have only a very basic understanding of the whole build process when dealing with cpp sources as I normally work with c# .net or android (without native sources).

From my understanding the ndk-build should give me some .so files that I can use in my app. But the build of the natives failes. Am I missing something in the process?

edit: I switched to eclipse and could build and run the code. Maybe I try to switch back to android studio in the future, but this is not so important.

Comment: replace the ndk task with what is specified here : http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your suggestion. In the meantime I switched to eclipse which supports the mk files. With this I could build and run my code. Thanks anyway

Comment: You should explicitly define STL for Android Studio, e.g. `stl "gnustl_static"`